# How to check if node is on TestNet or MainNet via `bitcoin-cli`?

Tags: json-rpc, testnet, bitcoin-cli

Is there a way, by using `bitcoin-cli` using RPC querying, if the node I'm querying is running on MainNet or TestNet?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since version 0.16.0

```
$ bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo

{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 525663,
  "headers": 525663, 
  .
  .
  .

}
```

Reference:
https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblockchaininfo.html

Answer (score 9):

Before version 0.16.0:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getinfo
{
  "version": 120100,
  "protocolversion": 70012,
  "walletversion": 60000,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 414105,
  "timeoffset": -165,
  "connections": 9,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 199312067531.243,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1466689642,
  "keypoolsize": 101,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "errors": ""
}
```

Comment: the `getinfo` command deprecated in Bitcoin Core 0.16 onwards. you'll get the message `the method not found` on later versions.

Comment: good to know, any replacement?

Comment: as @Kerem atam said, you can use `getblockchaininfo` as well as `getnetworkinfo` and `getwalletinfo` for some more information.